# How to capture video in H265 codec in Android

Tags: android, h.264, video-encoding, hevc, h.265

I trying to write a test app in Android that captures video with camera. Looking at the recorded videos on my device, apparently it uses H264 AVC1 by default. I know my particualar device supports HEVC (Samsung S10). How can I change the code to record videos in H.265?

```
   private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the video file name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Comment: Using Intents on Android has been a coarse request with support depending on OEM apps, notably the `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent has only been [required since Android 10](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd#7_5_cameras). As mentioned in: https://www.xda-developers.com/oems-change-default-video-capture-format-android-12-hevc/ not all OEMs support HEVC by default. My guess is that if you want to record in HEVC, you'll have to use an [existing open source video recorder](https://github.com/android/camera-samples)/write your own.

Comment: I know all don't support it. But only if supported, use hevc.

Comment: More FYI but it appears the [CameraX video capture library](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/video-capture) selects [codec based on device](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204112201) and I suspect that due to differences in device hardware along with HEVC recording never being mandated means that Google is trying to put some guidelines via [Android 12's Performance class](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/performance-class) for all of the video use cases as described in this [issue ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180151796#comment4)

Comment: Cool. I like to implement those feature using the SDK we currently have, like for Android 5+.